# 3D symbol transparency for polygonZ layer in 3D map view

Tags: symbology, rendering, transparency-opacity, multi-polygon, 3d-map

I have a MultiPolygonZ layer and I would like to add some transparency to its surfaces but in the [3D symbol for polygon layer](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/style_library/3d_symbols.html?highlight=3d%20view#polygon-layers) there is no opacity parameter (contrary to point and line layer). The surface shading doesn't accept transparency as alpha value (set to 1 and non-editable).

Is there a way to add some transparency to polygon facades in the 3D rendering ?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently opacity was an attribute for point and line layers but has been removed. I made a feature request on this subject on QGIS github page.

I tried in color choice window but alpha channel is not taken into account, and programmatically but hex color with alpha is transformed into random hex color.